# UseState renders me the previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have two inputs that change the text of a P tag at the same time, but the problem is that the render that shows me is always the previous value that was saved. I understand that I have to use a useEffect to render the component again and show the current value, but in the inputs handleChange if or if I need to send to the SetState that changes the text, the value that was saved in the initialValue. Until now I am learning React and I have already tried a lot of things, but nothing works for me, how could I implement the useEffect in this case? Thank you very much for the help.

```
const initialValue = {
  input1: 0,
  input2: 0,
};

const TestState = () => {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState(initialValue);
  const [textChange, setTextChange] = useState("-");

  useEffect(() => {}, [obj]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setObj({ ...obj, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    //Basically I need to do this -> setTextChange(e.target.value), but with the value stored in the initialValue.
    setTextChange(e.target.name === "input1" ? obj.input1 : obj.input2);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="input1" onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="text" name="input2" onChange={handleChange} />
      </form>
      <p>{textChange}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-mahavira-pd94p?file=/src/TestState.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter you get from `useState` (i.e. `setObj`) does not immediately alter the value/state of the object under control. The update occurs before the next render(). That is why your `obj` object appears to be stale.

Note, you don't need to replace the `obj` object itself, you're just updating its contents. You could just do this:

```
const [obj] = useState(initialValue);
...

const handleChange = (e) => {
  //setObj({ ...obj, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  setTextChange(e.target.name === "input1" ? obj.input1 : obj.input2);
}
```

Comment: wow dude, you taught me many things that I didn't know, for example that I could use a usestate without a setter or maybe just use a const, besides that I don't need to replace the entire object but only update its value/state, seriously thank you very much.

Comment: Excuse me, I have a question. If I do this, obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value, am I not directly mutating the state? I understand that this is a big no in React, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexGarzón The value of `obj` is a location in memory. If you change that (e.g. by creating a new object) then use `setObj()` to update it. It is OK to modify the contents of `obj` directly. That said, those changes won't trigger a re-render. That's why you'll see many people clone & update the object as you've done in your code above. The important thing is to understand the mechanics so you pick the approach that works best for you. e.g. you can clone & update the object, then just `setTextChange` to e.target.value` so it's not delayed. Up to you. Enjoy the journey!